# How to typecast set values in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am making the following query

```
neo4j-sh (?)$  start n=node(*) match n-[r:LIKES]->items with r,items set r.w= (r.ct-items.med)/items.iqr return r,items;
==> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> | r                                         | items                                 |
==> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> | :LIKES[293] {ct:3,w:-0.6666666666666666}  | Node[255]{name:"f1",iqr:6.0,med:7}    |
==> | :LIKES[294] {ct:13,w:1}                   | Node[256]{name:"f2",iqr:5,med:7}      |
==> | :LIKES[295] {ct:1,w:-0.7692307692307693}  | Node[257]{name:"f3",iqr:3.25,med:3.5} |
==> | :LIKES[304] {ct:3,w:0}                    | Node[256]{name:"f2",iqr:5,med:7}      |
==> | :LIKES[305] {ct:10,w:0.5}                 | Node[255]{name:"f1",iqr:6.0,med:7}        
==> | :LIKES[308] {ct:9,w:0.4}                  | Node[259]{name:"f5",iqr:7.5,med:6.0}  |
==> | :LIKES[313] {ct:2,w:-1}                   | Node[256]{name:"f2",iqr:5,med:7}      |
==> | :LIKES[314] {ct:3,w:-0.6666666666666666}  | Node[255]{name:"f1",iqr:6.0,med:7}    |
==> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Why is it that when the value of r.w is greater than one, it is rounded to the nearest integer? I tried to typecast it to double but I am getting error. What would be the right set command then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use floats to make it do float math:

```
start n=node(*) match n-[r:LIKES]->items with r set r.w= (r.ct-1.0)/5.0 return r;
```

Comment: No, the 1 and 5 are not constant they are integer values that I get from the items property Maybe I should edit my post.

Comment: Then multiply them by 1.0 to force the math to be float-based. Eventually we'll add casting to cypher, but it's not there yet.